# Can I create a ALB Listener with no Target Group (just want to return 404) for default route

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

When I create an ALB listener, it appears I need to set a `TargetGroupArn`.

But I was thing why not just return 404 ... I seem to be able to do this with `ActionType` of `fixed-response`. But even if I want to return a fixed-response, I need a target group? This does not seem to make sense?

Whats the best practice for default action?

Comment: You could probably add a Target Group that has no instances.

Comment: 404 is **page** not found, you should not return it if there are no servers to serve anything at all. If you attach an empty target group you should get a 503 or 504 which is the correct response when you don't have anything listening

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, ok will do that, but am just curious with AWS console, I can create an action with no target group https://imgur.com/a/l20FGAv

Comment: @arco444, good point, just curious, with AWS console, I can create an action with no target group https://imgur.com/a/l20FGAv

Comment: @arco444, then again ... its because the URL is incorrect no?

Comment: @JiewMeng A 404 indicates there is actually a server in play, it just doesn't know where to find the resource you requested. If you start receiving 404s when there are no servers it will complicate your debugging

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a listener with the following cloudformation snippet in conjunction with your ALB...

```
    HttpListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: fixed-response
        FixedResponseConfig:
          StatusCode: 404
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
```